# Internal server error,While querying data on UserFieldAccess Object to fetch the field accessibility of PriceBook2 or Product object only from LWC

Tags: apex, lightning-web-components, pricebook, gack, product2

I have an Apex class with a single apex method, where I am querying on UserFieldAccess object to get the field accessibility of Opportunity.PriceBook2 field for a particular user.

Apex class -

```
public with sharing class DummyClass {
@AuraEnabled
public static void demoCall(){
    try {
        UserFieldAccess ufa1 = [SELECT DurableId, IsAccessible, IsUpdatable, IsCreatable
                                FROM UserFieldAccess WHERE DurableId = 'Opportunity.Pricebook2.0055i000006KLY1' Limit 1];
        system.debug(ufa1);
    } catch (Exception e) {
        throw new AuraHandledException(e.getMessage());
    }
}
```

}

If the method is called from Anonymous window or the query is executed in query editor , then its returning value perfectly. But if I call the method from LWC then I am getting **'An internal server error has occurred\nError ID: 2105550198-142123 (-726492148)'**.

Also Its happening for every those object, in which there is a reference field of

- **Product**
- **PriceBook**

Comment: Can you share a sample lwc code  and also can you reproduce again the behaviour and share the time zone and time stamp of when the issue occurred.

Comment: @SaiPraveenKakkirala I have updated the post. And also in the lwc file I am just calling this apex method inside connectedCallback(). like this - 

connectedCallback(){
        demoCall({})
        .then(result => {
            console.log('success!');
        }).catch(error=>{
            console.error(error);
        });
    }

Comment: Thanks for sharing the code. Did you try reproducing the issue again and share the time zone and time stamp

Comment: Well I am facing this issue for last two weeks